# How to make an array of object from 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have any array like:

`a = ["name", "age"]` and then an array of arrays like `b = [["Alex", 20], ["Ari", 25], ..]`
I want to make an array of object that get its keys from `a` and values from `b`

```js
[{
  name: "Alex",
  age: 20
}, 
{
  name: "Ari",
  age: 25
}]
```

I tried the following:

```js
for (const arr of b) {
  Object.assign({}, arr)
}
```

which makes an object but doesn't use keys of array a.

Answer (score 1):

```
const a = ["name", "age"]
const b = [["Alex", 20], ["Ari", 25]]

const output = b.map(item => {
 return a.reduce((aggr, curr, i) => (aggr[curr] = item[i], aggr), {});
});

console.log(output);
```

However the code assumes the length of `a` always matches length of each item in `b`. Make sure to guard it properly.

In case you were pondering about the statement in parentheses `(aggr[curr] = item[i], aggr)`, this is JavaScript's [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which executes all comma-delimited statements and returns the value of the last one - in this case `aggr` (which we need to return for next iteration of `.reduce` to aggregate the object).

Answer (score -1):

If you want something in Python you can also try this.

```
my_list = []
a = ['name','age']
b = [['alex', 20], ['ari', 25], ['pete', 45], ['alf', 67]]

for person in b:
    temp = {}
    for i in range(len(a)):
        temp[a[i]] = person[i]
    my_list.append(temp)
```